# Access all RadComboxes with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How to access all RadComboxes change event in JQUERY in asp.net ?

```
$("input[type='text']").Change(function() {
    alert('changed');
});
```

Here I used input type as "text" because for RadComboxes we are having type as "text".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the className `.rcbInput` to select **RadCombobox**

```js
$("input[type='text'].rcbInput").change(function() {
  alert('changed');
});
```

Comment: you mean we have to place a className : .rcbInput for all  RadCombobox es?

Comment: No need to add manually. It will be added to the input while rendering.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It saved me lot of time.

Comment: @SrikanthReddy : Welcome :-)

Comment: But if I select the existing selected one, It is still firing the event. It's not handling whether it is already selected or new one selected ?

Comment: In that case below solution will help!

Comment: That was correct. But my page contains nearly 30+ dropdowns I have to check for all "OnClientSelectedIndexChanged" events. Is there a way to it dynamically ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onclientselectedindexchanged` attribute to execute a function on change. Please check below snippet.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function OnClientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs) {
        var item = eventArgs.get_item();
        sender.set_text("You selected " + item.get_text());
    }
</script>

<telerik:radcombobox 
    id="RadComboBox1" 
    runat="server" 
    onclientselectedindexchanged="OnClientSelectedIndexChanged">
</telerik:radcombobox>
```

Comment: Hai, can we make this dynamically for all dds ?

Comment: @SrikanthReddy yes you can use this function in all the radcombobox.
All you have to do is pass this function in onclientselectedindexchanged attribute of all other dds.